# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid Exception: Validation failed: "Something" must exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, array.prototype.map

I am adding all is needed to create a post, but am getting an error message saying "Facility must exist."
For some reason, the facility_id is capturing the name of the facility and not the ID.
I am setting state for facilities, and mapping / filtering for my dropdown. Please see below:

```js
function AddPostForm({ posts, handlePost})
{
  const [facilities, setFacilities] = useState ([])
  const [procedures, setProcedures] = useState ([])
  const uniques = procedures.map(procedure => procedure.procedure)
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index )
// console.log("unique procedures:", uniques)
  const uniqFacility = facilities.map(facility => facility.name).filter((value,index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/posts/${procedures}`)
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then(setProcedures);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/facilities")
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then(setFacilities);
  }, []);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    facility_id: "",
    procedure:'',
    date_of_procedure:'',
    date_of_invoice:'',
    patient_cost: "",
    insurance_cost: "",
    comments: ""
  })

  const { id } = useParams();

  function handleChange(event) {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,[event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    handlePost(formData)

return (
    <div >
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       <label htmlFor="facility_id">Facility:</label>
      <select
        id="facility_id"
        name="facility_id"
        value={formData.facility_id}
        onChange={handleChange}      >
        <option value="">Select Facility</option>
        {uniqFacility.map((facility) => (
          <option key={facility.id} value={facility.name}>
            {facility}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
 </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AddPostForm;
```

When I check params in the byebug I see facility_id=>"Name of Facility", and get an error message saying that Facility must exist. I tried adjusting the map / filter function to ...facility => facility.id).filter ... , which ends up giving me the facility_id and creates the post as if the name of the entity was its id.
I think I need to adjust the map/filter formula, but I do not know how. Appreciate if someone help me out here.

Comment: you need to set the value in your options to the id, not the name. ```<option value={facility.id}>
            {facility.name}
          </option>```

Comment: tks, @dbugger. I do not see any facility name when is setting <option value={facility.id}>{facility.name}</option>.The console.log shows me the facilities like:(4) ["Facility A", "Facility B","Facility C","Facility D"] without any indication of its id. I noticed that the facility name will only display in the dropdown if I have {facility} prior closing the </option>. With that, I get the validation failed: Facility must exist. Anything u recommend adjusting in this formula:  const uniqFacility= facilities.map(facility=>facility.name).filter((value,index, self)=>self.indexOf(value) === index)?

Comment: look at your code -- see where you are setting the value

Comment: tks, @dbugger. Following ur lead I found out that the value I was getting was something else, not facilities. With that, I ended up doing a different formula and it worked. This is the new formula: const uniqueList = [...new Map(facilities.map((facility)=> [facility["name"], facility])).values()];